# Android activity showing with 2 views at the same time

Tags: android, view

I would like to know if its possible to have the same time in the view 2 files associated. One of them just filling 20% on the bottom of the view and another view file on the 80% remaining

Thank you.

Comment: you need a fragment then you can achieve

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use Fragment

References:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm